# Filter mapped on forward dispatcher isn't invoked when JSF navigation is performed

Tags: java, jsf, servlet-filters

I'm trying to code a simple JSF web application with a login system using Tomcat 7.

I have got two pages: index.xhtml and /restricted/welcome.xhtml.

Pages below "/restricted/*" shall be only accessible to users logged in.

Surfing directly to the welcome.xhtml causes my filter to be executed, forwarding from index.xhtml to welcome.xhtml bypasses the filter. I can't imagine why the filter is not executed.

RestrictedAreaFilter.java:

```java
@WebFilter(value = { "/restricted/*" }, dispatcherTypes = { DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.ASYNC, DispatcherType.ERROR, DispatcherType.INCLUDE })
public class RestrictedAreaFilter implements Filter {

@Override
public void destroy() {

}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest httpReq = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    User user = (User) httpReq.getSession().getAttribute("user");

    if (user != null && user.isLoggedIn()) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } else {
        httpReq.getRequestDispatcher("/access_denied.xhtml").forward(request, response);
    }
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {

}

}
```

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html
PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<head>
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<h:form id="form">
    <h:panelGrid id="grid" columns="2">
        <h:outputLabel value="Benutzername" for="username" />
        <h:inputText id="username" value="#{login.username}" />
        <h:outputLabel value="Passwort:" for="password" />
        <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{login.password}">
            <f:validateLength minimum="4" maximum="16" />
        </h:inputSecret>
        <h:message style="color: red" for="password" />

    </h:panelGrid>
    <h:commandButton id="login" value="Login" action="#{login.proceed}" />
</h:form>
</body>
</html>
```

```java
@ManagedBean(name = "login")
@RequestScoped
public class LoginBean {

@ManagedProperty(value = "#{user}")
private User user;

private String username;
private String password;

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String proceed() {
    user.setLoggedIn(true);

    return "restricted/welcome.xhtml";
}
}
```

Comment: scope of bean User ? Try deleting  the cookies and retry the access

Comment: Hi Jigar Joshi.

The User bean is session scoped. Tested it with deleted cookies and a new browser.

Comment: You are making a GET request directly to `welcome.xhtml` , right?

Comment: When use directly .../restricted/welcome.xhtml in the browser, of course it's a get request, the form from index.xhtml accesses the welcome.xhtml vie post method.

Comment: well I am asking that in which case Filter doesn't work as expected, do one thing, clear all the cookies and try making a GET to /restricted/welcome.xhtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FORWARD` dispatcher is only triggered when [`RequestDispatcher#forward()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) is been invoked somewhere in the webapp's code. The standard JSF navigation handler doesn't do that. It just invokes [`ViewHandler#createView()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/ViewHandler.html#createView%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20java.lang.String%29) and sets it as current view by [`FacesContext#setViewRoot()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#setViewRoot%28javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot%29).

Send a redirect instead:

```
public String proceed() {
    user.setLoggedIn(true);

    return "restricted/welcome.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

This is by the way also the recommended practice. Now it's a bookmarkable page (the URL change is now reflected in browser's address bar) and refreshing/F5'ing the page won't result in the POST unnecessarily being re-executed and pressing back button won't result in surprises.

If you really insist in invoking the `FORWARD` dispatcher using JSF, you can always use [`ExternalContext#dispatch()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#dispatch%28java.lang.String%29) method, but this is **not** the recommended way.

```
public void proceed() throws IOException {
    user.setLoggedIn(true);

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().dispatch("restricted/welcome.xhtml")
}
```

Comment: when OP makes direct get without making any POST, OP is able to view that page, see comments under question

Comment: @Jigar: That's a different problem.